# Amortized analysis for disjoint sets' find-set(x) function (from CLRS)

Tags: amortized-analysis, disjoint-sets

I start off by apologizing for the fact that I don't really know how to use latex/markdown. My question, however, is directly from the Introduction To Algorithms book by Cormen et al. The topic discusses about the time analysis for disjoint set operations using forests with union-by-rank and path-compression heuristics. In particular, I am stuck at Lemma 21.13 (580) for which the "find-set(x)" subroutine is claimed to run at `O(alpha(n))` time where alpha(n) is the inverse Ackermann function. I cannot arrive to the conclusion that there is at most `alpha(n)+2` nodes in the find path that satisfy some specific conditions. This node count comes from the maximum number of nodes where the `level(x)` is constant across the find path if my interpretation is correct. I assume it is an obvious outcome of previously proven lemmas. Unfortunately, I am not so bright to validate this result.

Of course, without the details about the potential function, this question cannot be answered. There is a big problem, besides that I cannot elegantly type it out in latex. There is a ton of lemmas that logically weave this proof. So, I assume that you have the text with you. Just in case if all of this is obvious to you, here are the fundamentals.

A really really big function:
1st arg -> subscript (denotes the "level" (the notation also seems to be native within the book))
2nd arg -> superscript (denotes the number iterations of the same function)
3rd arg -> the actual input

$A(0,1, j) = j+1$
$A(k,1, j) = A(k-1,j+1,j) \mid k \ge 1$

its inverse for j = 1:
$alpha(n) = \min\{k : A(k,1,1) \ge n\}$

two auxiliary functions needed to define potential function:
//note that x is the node and x.p is its parent node, x.rank is its rank (the thing that increments monotonically traversing up)

level(x) = max {k: x.p.rank >= A(k,1,x.rank)}
iter(x) = max {i: x.p.rank >= A(level(x), i, x.rank)}

The potential function is then defined as:
//n is node count, q is the qth operation in the system, x is the node

phi(q,x) = alpha(n) * x.rank ; if x is not a root or x.rank = 0
phi(q,x) = (alpha(n) - level(x)) * x.rank - iter(x) ; if x is not a root and x.rank >= 1

Again, I emphasize that this question is really specific about the literature because it is not so obvious as to how all this and the $alpha(n)+2$ path length is necessary to prove the bound. But, I am open to other proofs where the `find-set(x)` subroutine (the one which compresses the path in after finding the root) is a superconstant.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is actually quite simple. Just like in the book, let us assume that the find path consists of $s$ nodes. We disregard the root (because its potential doesn't change at all after the operation) and the node we upon which `find_set` is called (because it may have rank 0, which means its potential might not change). This leaves us with $s-2$ nodes.

Now, consider any node $z$ among the remaining $s-2$ nodes. As explained on pages 576-577 (I am using the 3rd edition), we have $0 \le \operatorname{level}(z) < \alpha(n)$. In other words, the level of $z$ must be between 0 and $\alpha(n) - 1$, inclusive. Indeed, it is the fact that we have
a finite number of options for the levels of the aforementioned $s-2$ nodes that will help us prove the assertion presented by the authors.

They say one example is worth a thousand words, so let's do one. Suppose we have 8 nodes between the root and the one upon which `find_set` was called. Suppose also that $\alpha(n)$ turns out to be $4$. Here's one possibility for the levels of the nodes, given in the order they appear in the find path:

$$ 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0 $$

The book claims that there are at most $\alpha(n)$ (4 in our case) nodes $x$ for which there doesn't exist a node y later in the path such that $\operatorname{level}(x) = \operatorname{level}(y)$. Take a good look at the sequence; you'll see that the claim holds for our example.

Now, the million dollar question. Why? Think about the last $\alpha(n)$ nodes. We could assign different levels to each one (as I have done for this example) so that none of them have a complementary node higher up the find path with the same level. However, that is the most we can have; every other node will now have some ancestor with the same level. Long story short, no matter how hard we try, we cannot have more than $\alpha(n)$ nodes without an ancestor of equal level; such a scenario would require more options for the level of a node than are available.

Put it all together, and it is evident that there exists another node with the same level down the line for at least $s - \alpha(n) - 2$ of the $s$ nodes, just like the book claims.

As for why the authors have found it unnecessary to provide an explanation for their claim, you are asking the wrong guy.